# Windows command line Pass Input (2 strings) to Exe

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have a utility (myprog.exe) that requires a login an password to function. It has an .ini file for ID and Password , but for some reason it will not use the values I put in to the ini file (i think it is supposed to auto-update the ini file but that doesn't happen), so I'm trying to come up with a workaround.

If from a .bat file i run

```
echo <USER ID> | myappp.exe
```

this correctly passes the ID number to he program, and it advances to the PW input. If I type the PW and press [Enter], the program works correctly(image is the output of running the above command from batch file). All I want to do is pass this keyboard input for the PW on to the program . I've tried a few different syntax form for a 2nd echo command by they didn't work, or hang the program somehow.

I didn't write the utility, an the author is unable to offer further assistance.

[dos output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtVtv.png)

Editing the batch file and adding a 2nd echo command

```
echo <password> | myappp.exe
```

in any syntax form, or trying to call a 2nd batch file after the first echo command

```
echo <USER ID> | myappp.exe
call 2ndinput.bat
```

all attempt have given the same result:

[2nd input string result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POCJ3.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the things you tried and what the result was.

Comment: for formatting superuser ruins the formatting of code and various things, to prevent that you can highlight the code and then the brackets or quotes  button.clicking one or the other formats it as code or as a quote, i've just edited your question and done it.  I   notice that superuser actually deleted where you wrote <user id> , which is really bad design from superuser/stackoverflow but anyhow.. When formatting it as code then it keeps it in.

Answer (score 1):

The piping input to a command only works when the command prompts for keyboard input. (And even then not always e.g. it doesn't work for the 'runas' command)

You can use vbscript(bundled with win7), and its sendkeys function though. (Though bear in mind it's a bit limited in that it doesn't support unicode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198574/does-or-can-vbscripts-sendkeys-support-unicode )   But that limitation won't affect you. Note, C#'s sendkeys supports unicode.

blah.vbs

```
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
dim a, b
arg1 = objArgs(0)
arg2 = objArgs(1)
WshShell.SendKeys "blahprogram " + arg1 + "{Enter}" + arg2 + "{Enter}"
```

So if you run blah.vbs abc def

it will run  `C:\>blahprogram abc<ENTER>def<ENTER>`

You could make the sendkeys line

`WshShell.SendKeys "blahprogram" + "{Enter}" + "123" + "{Enter}"`

Then it will do

`C:\>blahprogram<ENTER>123<ENTER>`

If you want to run

`C:\>echo.| blahprogram<ENTER>123<ENTER>`

You can use the line

`WshShell.SendKeys "echo.|blahprogram" + "{Enter}" + "123" + "{Enter}"`

So your whole program would be

```
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
WshShell.SendKeys "echo.|blahprogram" + "{Enter}" + "123" + "{Enter}"
```

Comment: Where do I create the VBS script (?)

Comment: @IRacingMuskoka   You open notepad (or whatever you would use to write a batch script), but instead of saving your file as `blah.bat` you save it as `blah.vbs`  To run it you can try typing `blah.vbs<ENTER>`  or you could do `cscript blah.vbs<ENTER>`    or `cscript //nologo blah.vbs<ENTER>`

Comment: Maybe its late, but more likely I missed something.

Comment: I created the BLAH.VBS script (BETTERTPVBS.VBS) in the first part of your example. Just changed the name of blahprogram to bettertp

I then modified my BETTERTP-VBS.BAT file to:

**bettertpvbs <UID#> <PW>**

When I run BETTERTP-VBS.BAT, The output of that was 

**E:\> bettertp-vps

E:\> bettertp <UID> <PW>

E:\> bettertp <UID> 
useage: bettertp [-h] [-v] [--test FILE_NAME] [--no-update]
bettertp: error: unrecognized arguments:  <UID#>

E:\> <PW>
'<PW>' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry, comment not letting me format the answer clearly...

Comment: @IRacingMuskoka it's not `.vbs.bat` it's `.vbs`  it's not a bat file There's no bat file in what i'm describing. You can call it `bettertp.vbs`  no hiphen and don't use the word bat anywhere in it as that is just confusing.

Comment: also just run `bettertp.vps` (that's the vps program we/I/you wrote) with no parameters, and use the last three lines in my answer as your program and see what happens and then modify the vbs program accordingly

Comment: I confused my answer with the reference to the BAT file, I did create the VBS file. I ran it with the command from a bat file however.

I'm not really much of a programmer, I'm sorry. I just don't follow your instructions. Too many variable statements, and not sure which I'm supposed to interpret or substitute. I'm sure your effort is elegant enough, I just cannot fathom it.

Comment: @IRacingMuskoka start off by looking into how to write a VBS program that just prints "hello" on the screen(it's one line so doesn't really require programming skill).  Run it from the command line. Then try to run that program from a batch file.  If you have a question about how to do the first of those things then you could make a separate question for that. There is a stack overflow question called vbscript output to console, that has that one line. Once you can do that, then you can think about how to try the code I mentioned and tell me where you get stuck

Comment: Also I'd note that it's not good to be doing things when you don't understand it at all..  And it's really not hard to figure out how to write a one line program, run it, run it from a batch file. Then when you have acquired that knowledge. you can ask where you are stuck

Comment: Infact after you learn how to write a basic one line program, you could even take the last three lines I wrote  and replace that sendkeys line to just sendkeys "asdf".  And run the program and see what it does. HINT- it will type 'asdf' automatically.  And if you get stuck then state where

Comment: You claim that you ran the program(that's the three line program). Did you not see it even autotype blahprogram ?  There is not a single variable there that you(or I), need to change.